# What's a good thing to start with for developing a simple filtering filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, linux-kernel

I want to write a simple filtering pass-through filesystem for linux. It's supposed to handle permissions and owners correctly, so FUSE is out of the question. What's a good thing to start with? Reading the documentation and writing this thing from scratch is probably going to be tiresome, is there anything I can reuse?

Comment: Huh? How is this not constructive? Do you think people will start fighting over which filesystem code template is best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found http://wrapfs.filesystems.org/ - looks great so far.

Comment: wrapfs is good,I haven't tried it though.IF I'm not wrong,I think fuse should be able to handle permission too.